# Modelling environments (simple test environment) for gazebo

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

for some tests and validation between our real robot and my simulated robot
I want to build a simple environment in Gazebo (recreation of a simple floor or room in our
university).

Which program or tool would you propose to for this task (without the need of studying a whole book before)?

Thanks for your help,

Christoph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4311/modelling-environments-(simple-test-environment)-for-gazebo/) by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can directly insert simple shapes into Gazebo. Anything more complex will require the use of a 3D modeling application like Blender, 3DS Max, Maya, etc.

Here is how to import meshes into Gazebo:

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/beginner/mesh_import

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on 2013-09-23**:
Ok. So I have to do some reading etc.